# Hadoop Name Node Formatting fail

Tags: 16.04, hadoop

I am using [following tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10) to install Hadoop on my system and have followed all the steps uptil formatting the name node when the command

`hdfs namenode -format`

is giving me error:

`NFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/current`

I have followed following question as well [Error when formatting the Hadoop filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35551/error-when-formatting-the-hadoop-filesystem)

but its still not working. Can anyone kindly help. Ubuntu's version is 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the error is because the particular directory cannot be created. 
make sure that the /usr/local/hadoop_store is having the same permissions and ownership as HADOOP_HOME. You can check the ownership by ls -al command and you can use the following commands for changing 
the ownership:

```
chown -R [OWNER]:[GROUP] [Directory name]
```

and the permissions:

```
chmod -R [OWNER]:[GROUP] [Directory name]
```

The link stated by has correct instructions and your JAVA_HOME also looks perfect as it is able to invoke Java but I am doubtful that hadoop has access of hadoop_data directory.

Comment: Thanks. I will post detailed comment after checking the issue again